# How can I maintain a counter when using map on a list?

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

This is for a class assignment.

I am to implement a function in ML `evalxy poly x y` where `poly` is an `int list list` that represents a polynomial. A term at position `n` in its inner list and position `m` in the outer list is the coefficient for `x^n * y^m`. For example, the list `[[1],[0,~2,0,0,3],[],[],[],[],[~5,0,7]]` represents the polynomial `1 - 2x + 3 * x^4 * y - 5 * y^6 + 7 * x^2 * y^6`.

The function `evalxy` is to evaluate the given polynomial using the given values for x and y. The type of the function is to be `val evalxy = fn : int list list -> int -> int -> int`. An example is `evalxy [[1],[0,~2,0,0,3],[],[],[],[],[~5,0,7]] ~1 1 = 8`.

I'm not allowed to define any other top-level functions, I'm not allowed to use a let-expression, and I'm not allowed to use recursion except for `map`, `foldr`, and `foldl`. Those are also the only built-in functions I'm allowed to use.

I figure that I could do this by calling `map` on the outer list, calling `map` on each inner list, and for each inner list item I multiply the entry (the coefficient) by x and y. If I initialized the x and y counters to 1 each, then for the first entry (e.g. coefficients 0 and 0) then coefficient * 1 * 1 will return the coefficient, which is the expected value for exponents of 0. Then for each iteration of the outer list I could increment the y counter by the result of multiplying the counter by the provided y-value. For example, `1 * y = y` (for y^1, since it's initialized to 1), `y * y` (for y^2). The same could be done for the x counter and the inner lists.

I realize that's not terribly clear. What I'm getting at is, for the first iterations of the outer list, some y counter (say, `ycounter`) has the value:

- **First iteration:** `1`
- **Second iteration:** `1 * y`
- **Third iteration:** `1 * y * y`
- *and so on*

The problem is, I don't know how I could maintain such a counter. Am I completely on the wrong track here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, but those don't seem to help as they're suggesting things that are forbidden. Specifically, let-expressions and recursion.

Comment: Those URLs specifically contain solutions to your problem that don't use let-expressions and only use higher-order list combinators, rather than direct recursion. This still very much seems like a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks then, I'll investigate it more deeply once the game is over.